# Replacing Regex String in C#

Tags: c#, replace, expression

I have a `Regexrule.cs`Class, it consists of the following properties:

```
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public string FirstOpen { get; set; }
    public string FirstClose { get; set; }
    public string SecondOpen { get; set; }
    public string SecondClose { get; set; }
```

`Expression` holds a **Regular Expression** value, and it is always expected to return 2 Groups.

The four fields (excluding `Expression`) are prefixes and suffixes for the two groups that are expected to be found... so that this happens:

`FirstOpen + Group[1] + FirstClose` and `SecondOpen + Group[2] + SecondClose`

Anyway, I have a `List<RegexRule> Rules;` that contains a list of `RegexRules` objects.

> **The Predicament**

My goal is to loop through each one one those (`RegexRules r`), run its respective expression (`r.Expression`)  on a particularly long string, and when the two expected groups are found, I want the script to encapsulate each group with its prefixes and suffixes in the way shown...again,

`r.FirstOpen + Group[1] + r.FirstClose` and `r.SecondOpen + Group[2] + r.SecondClose`

I've tried many different ways but one thing I know is that `str.Replace` isn't going to work, in a loop. Because it will apply the prefixes and suffixes over and over, for every occurrence of the expression's results.

So how else can this be achieved?

Thank you.

> Edit

This is what I've currently got:

```
foreach (RegexRule r in RegexRules.ToList())
{ 
    Regex rx = new Regex(r.Expression); 
    MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(str); 
    foreach (Match m in mc) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show("replacing");
         str = str.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, r.OpenBBOne + m.Groups[1].Value + r.CloseBBOne);
    }
}
```

> Edit 2 - Specifics

Users will create their own Regex configurations in a `.config` file, and it will be in this format:

`reg {(\w+).(\w+)\(\);} = [("prefix1","suffix1"),("prefix2","suffix2")];`

---

`reg` - Standard word for defining a new RegexRule

---

`{ {(\w+).(\w+)\(\); }` - Their Regular expression (CONDITION: expression must always return 2 groups in its matches)

---

`[("prefix1","suffix1"),("prefix2","suffix2")]` - Two parameters in `[("","") , ("","")] - which represent the prefixes and suffixes for the two groups

**Example **

If we applied the above configuration to this string:

`Lorem ipsum foo.bar(); dolor sit bar.foo(); amit consecteteur...`

The regex would capture `foo.bar()` as a match, in that `foo` is match[1] group[1], and `bar` is match[1] group[2], according to the regular expression.

Same goes for `bar.foo()`, because `bar` is match[2] group[1], and `foo` match[2] group[2]

I hope this makes sense...

Comment: This really feels like you're trying to force a design pattern that doesn't fit the actual need.  You might want to back up a step and try to look at what you're doing from a different angle.  My $.02

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I don't know... how else could it be done?

Comment: @BarryD, Suppose, you've got `([0-9]).([a-z])` as a regex and `1aa1` as an input string. Do you want *both* `1`s to be replaced or only the first one (i.e. one matching the regex)?

Comment: @BarryD. I'm not sure, I don't know what need you're trying to satisfy with this approach.  But usually when I see people having problems with highly flexible code (like regex stuff) and trying to wrap structure around it, it's been a case of going down the wrong path on design.  The problem is usually that you're trying to do something you shouldn't need to do.  As for what that is in this case, I don't have anything of value to offer.  Just be careful that your technical implementation is actually solving a business problem and not a problem of your own making.

Comment: Is there some reason why your `List<RegexRule>` cannot have unique values? If it was able to have unique values, would that not fix your problem, and you'd be able to use `string.Replace()`? Can you provide a sample of the input you use and the incorrect output you get?

Comment: Users can create their own Regex configuration, in the application. They set an expression (which always has to return 2 groups, that's the catch on the Users side) and they set 1 prefix and 1 suffix for each group. I want to create code that's flexible enough to apply the user's REGEXs against a certain string and cover any of the matches (again,  will be in 2 groups, always) in the proper prefixes and suffixes. That is my goal.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the end result to look like exactly? The way it seems is that you want something like PrefixText1fooSuffixText1.PrefixText1barSuffixText1() for the first `Expression` and PrefixText2barSuffixText2.PrefixText2fooSuffixText2() for the second. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess what I am missing is why this is such an issue. Is there some reason you cannot keep the foo.bar() string connected, do a `string.Replace()` on that match value (the full foo.bar()), save the new string, and then replace foo.bar() with your new pre- and suffixed foo.bar() in the "particularly long string?" Am I missing something?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But the problem is, for every instance of "foo.bar()" found in the particularly long string, the prefixes and suffixes are applied AGAIN on top of the already applied ones, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion, I think this might be a solution for you. It has to do with the first comment I made. It gives you unique values for your `MatchCollection` using `.Distinct()` so that you don't end up compounding the prefixes and suffixes.

```
foreach(RegexRule r in RegexRules.ToList())
{ 
    Regex rx = new Regex(r.Expression); 
    MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(str); 
    foreach(Match m in mc.OfType<Match>().Distinct()) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show("replacing");
         str = str.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, 
                           r.OpenBBOne + m.Groups[1].Value + r.CloseBBOne);
    }
}
```

If you can't use LINQ for some reason, you can always just basically do the same thing yourself by creating a new `List<Match>` and only adding in the ones that aren't yet in the list.

```
foreach(RegexRule r in RegexRules.ToList())
{ 
    Regex rx = new Regex(r.Expression); 
    MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(str);

    List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    foreach(Match m in mc)
        if(!strings.Contains(m.Value))
        {
            matches.Add(m);
            strings.Add(m.Value);
        }

    foreach(Match m in matches) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show("replacing");
         str = str.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value, 
                           r.OpenBBOne + m.Groups[1].Value + r.CloseBBOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was not only difficult to explain, but I genuinely could not get past it, and you presented the only solution that I have, without exception. And it worked. Thank you very much sir!! 

But: `mc.Distinct();` won't work because it's a `MatchCollection`, thank you for the alternative :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right. I forgot you have to define the type so you can get the enumerator. I've edited my answer so it should work for you with LINQ.